# Problema com overflow biblioteca numpy(Não gera gráfico)

Tags: python, modelagem, gráfico, numpy

Eu estou programando um código que , a partir de uma função matemática, gera um gráfico. Esta função matématica é definida como : (Vs/R)*(1-e^(-Rt/L))*função degrau. Vs,R e L são valores de circuito. O problema é que o codigo retorna um aviso de overflow na pa

```
<ipython-input-20-e487152b00b1>:21: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp 
VLs0 = (vs/r)*(1-np.exp(-L0))*degrau
<ipython-input-20-e487152b00b1>:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
VLs0 = (vs/r)*(1-np.exp(-L0))*degrau
```

Isso  é repetido para todas as variaveis do código que usam a função exponencial, gostaria de resolver isso. Infelizmente não posso alterar os valores do cirucito elétrico simulado....
Segue o código:

```
    #Definindo Variáveis
t = np.linspace(-0.1, 1, 1000) # cria um vetor de tempo, indo de -0,1s a 1s, com 1000 pontos igualmente espaçados
degrau = np.zeros_like(t) # cria um vetor de zeros, do mesmo formato que o vetor t
mask = t > 0 # cria uma máscara que seleciona todas as posições onde t é maior ou igual a zero
degrau[mask] = 1 # transforma todos os valores do vetor degrau, que estão na posição da mascara, em 1
#---------------------#
#PLOT TESTE
#plt.plot(t, vs) # faz um gráfico com o vetor t no eixo x e o vetor degrau no eixo y
#plt.xlabel('tempo (s)') # dá nome ao eixo x
#plt.ylabel('Degrau unitário: $u(t)$ (V)') # dá nome ao eixo y
#plt.show()
#VARIAVEIS GERAIS
vs = 5*degrau
rt = 1/1000
r = 1000
#Indutor
L0 = r*t/0.0001
L1 = r*t/0.0002
L2 = r*t/0.0003
#CODIGO VLs
VLs0 = (vs/r)*(1-np.exp(-L0))*degrau
VLs1 = (vs/r)*(1-np.exp(-L1))*degrau
VLs2 = (vs/r)*(1-np.exp(-L2))*degrau

#PLOTS
#CODIGO Is
i0 = (vs/r)*(1-np.exp(-L0))*degrau
i1 = (vs/r)*(1-np.exp(-L1))*degrau
i2 = (vs/r)*(1-np.exp(-L2))*degrau
plt.plot(t,i0)
plt.plot(t,i1)
plt.plot(t,i2)
#CODIGO Vrs
```

Eu acredito que o erro está em L0,L1 e L2 por causa de ser valores que forçam uma exponencial grande na formula, mas teria como contornar isso sem alterar valores e gerar um gráfico como o esperado?

Comment: Sua conclusão sobre o que gera o erro parece está correta, então é precisamos saber qual formula/função matemática é essa para determinar se há algum erro na tradução dessa para python ou se é caso de uso de números com precisão arbitrária(testei seu código com `np.float128` e não foi suficiente). Sem mais informações o que posso fazer é isso, aqui `L0 = r*t/0.0001` gera um número de magnitude elevada(mesmo é valido para `L1` e `L2`) não seria `L0 = r*t*0.0001` ?

Answer (score -6):

Podes ignorar os warnings:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: Poxa, o usuário está se queixando do programa não gerar gráficos e você sugere como solução desligar os alertas? Não é legal fazer isso com quem está passando por dificuldades.

Comment: Mas funciona. Consegue gerar o gráfico dessa maneira.

Comment: @tomasantunes funcionar é diferente de estar certo. Por mais que funcione, pode levar o usuário à cometer um erro que no futuro pode ser grave ou ser bem difícil de corrigir.